# Mechanisms to be root after ssh login (w/o using sudo)

Tags: ssh, root, rhel-6, elevated

Our servers are set-up in a way, that after ssh'ing to them using our userid  `ssh my_user@server`(I am immediately greeted with `[root@server ~]#`
The command `id` confirms that, indeed, I am root.
However, I do end up in my own home directory `/home/my_user`.
I've tried to find clues as how this is set up, but neither sshd_config, /etc/passwd or /etc/group shows anything out of the ordinary
Any idea how this is achieved ?

I do think this is not really a secure set up and I plan to do things different in the near future (we are about to upgrade our OSes), but I still like to understand

Comment: I suppose someone set this up. We can guess; they just know. Did you ask them first? What did they say?

Comment: What uid does the `my_user` account have? (Check `id my_user` and `getent passwd my_user`.)

Comment: Try looking for it in the shell startup files, `/etc/profile` and the ones under `/etc/profile.d` or `/etc/bashrc` or similar if it exists, also in your home, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`. This is probably implemented with a call to `sudo`, look for that... Also check that your user can `sudo` without a password, which would probably be needed... Your normal home directory is kept by preserving the `$HOME` environment variable, normally after login that's what is used (and not necessarily the entry from `/etc/passwd` anymore.)

Comment: @user1686 Please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it as the answer ! Thx